# Removing duplicated rows from pandas time series dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I'm trying to remove duplicated time series data from a pandas dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# original data
df = pd.DataFrame()
np.random.seed(0)
days = pd.to_datetime(['2015-01-01', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-03', '2015-01-04', '2015-01-04', '2015-01-05', '2015-01-06', '2015-01-06', '2015-01-07', '2015-01-08'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': days, 'col1': np.random.randn(len(days))})
df = df.set_index('Date')

#df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='df.index')

print(df)

# remove duplicates, keep first instance
n = np.where(df.index.duplicated())[0]

print(n)

df0 = df.drop(df.iloc[n.tolist()])

print(df0)
```

The `drop_duplicates` command doesn't work, so I tried using `iloc`, which gives me this error:

```
KeyError: "['col1'] not found in axis"
```

Comment: `df.groupby(level=0)['col1'].first()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
print(df[~df.index.duplicated()])
```

Prints:

```
                col1
Date                
2015-01-01  1.764052
2015-01-02  0.400157
2015-01-03  0.978738
2015-01-04  2.240893
2015-01-05 -0.977278
2015-01-06  0.950088
2015-01-07 -0.103219
2015-01-08  0.410599
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset='Date').set_index('Date')
```

Output:

```
             col1
Date    
2015-01-01  1.764052
2015-01-02  0.400157
2015-01-03  0.978738
2015-01-04  2.240893
2015-01-05  -0.977278
2015-01-06  0.950088
2015-01-07  -0.103219
2015-01-08  0.410599
```